# $\int_9^{16} f(x)dx = 64$, what is value of $\int_9^{16} f(x^2)xdx$

Tags: definite-integrals, substitution

Confused on the final step and want to double check my work.

Say $\int_9^{16} f(x)dx = 64$, what is value of $\int_9^{16} f(x^2)xdx$

I used u substitution and set $u = x^2$,  then $\frac{du}{2} = xdx$

Changed the bounds since $u=x^2$, take the square root of each.

Then $\frac{1}{2}\int_3^{4} f(u)du =$ ?

Comment: no way of knowing. On the other hand, you could do $\int_3^4 f(x^2)x dx$

Comment: When you integrate you will need change the bounds on your integral to accommodate your substitution...

Answer (score 3):

No, you have not changed your limits of integration from $x$ to $u$.

Notice that if $$x=9, u=x^2=81$$

We simply do not have enough information to find $$ \int_9^{16} f(x^2)xdx$$

Comment: Ok, this makes sense to me now. Thank you.